# Error composing bindable: Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'router' of null

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Before the last update to aurelia framework I used to be able to replace

```
<nav-bar router.bind="router"></nav-bar>
```

with

```
<compose view-model="./nav-bar" model.bind="router"></compose>
```

in app.html of skeleton-navigation

This doesn't work anymore. 
Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'router' of null

In fact, none of my compose work with upgraded aurelia. Is there a problem with compose at the moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nav-bar has a `router` property decorated with the `@bindable` decorator.  There's no way to bind the nav-bar custom element's router property to the app view-model's router property using compose.

In general, `compose` and `@bindable` are not related features.  There's no way to translate this:

```html
<my-custom-element my-bindable-property.bind="foo"></my-custom-element>
```

To this:

```html
<!-- no way to bind "my-bindable-property"... binding to "model" is not going to help -->
<compose view-model="./my-custom-element"></compose>
```

Try changing your compose to this:

```html
<compose view="./nav-bar.html"></compose>
```

You can delete nav-bar.js as well- it won't be used.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question. [According to Aurelia's documentation](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#compose) this is possible: <template repeat.for="item of items">
    <compose
      model.bind="item"
      view-model="widgets/${item.type}">
    </compose>
</template>

Comment: Is it no longer possible to bind objects with compose?

Comment: thanks for pointing out that compose and bindable shouldn't be used together.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass objects to `compose` Custom Element I had to set element like this:

`<compose view-model="./nav-bar" model.bind="router"></compose>`

and then use `activate` method to assign that object in the model:

```
export class NavBar {
  activate(router){
    this.router = router;
  }
}
```

As Jeremy pointed out `compose` and `@bindable` no longer work together...

Comment: did you try `<compose view="./nav-bar.html"></compose>` ?  Then you wouldn't need nav-bar.js at all

Comment: yes, that works as well. I understand the compose custom element uses the view-model of the parent in this case.